# How to track the origin of a error in my reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

In a component, and only on one component, I get a bunch (like 20 or 30, I don't really know) of errors like these one after another:

```
TypeError: u is undefined
    r c:10
    s c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    e c:10
    d c:10
    onCommitFiberRoot c:10
    React 2
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:646
    React 4
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:646
    React 5
    requestToken token.ts:135
index.js:1
    e index.js:1
    d c:10
    onCommitFiberRoot c:10
    React 2
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:646
    React 4
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:646
    React 5
    requestToken token.ts:135
```

after I fill my login form and hit 'submit', which calls a function called `requestToken` and redirects to `/c` in the browser.

This is the content of `token.ts`

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosResponse } from 'axios'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'
import { Rules, useAbilityDispatch } from 'modules/ability/ability'
import { notifyNetworkError } from 'modules/notification/notification'
import { makeAuthUser } from 'modules/resource/resource'
import moment from 'moment'
import React from 'react'
import { Token, Tokens } from 'types/monolith'

const ls_key = 'auth-token'

type getTokenResp = {
  tokens: string | undefined
  updating: boolean
  error: AxiosError<Tokens> | undefined
}

export const useAuth = () => {
  const [jwt, setJwt] = React.useState<Tokens | null>(null)
  const [isUpdating, setIsUpdating] = React.useState(false)
  const [isError, setIsError] = React.useState<AxiosError<Tokens> | undefined>(
    undefined
  )
  const dispatch = useAbilityDispatch()

  const storeToken = (t: Tokens) => {
    setJwt(t)
    window.localStorage.setItem(ls_key, JSON.stringify(t))
  }

  const retrieveToken = (): Tokens | null => {
    const jwt_string = window.localStorage.getItem(ls_key)
    if (jwt_string === null) {
      return null
    }

    const tokens = JSON.parse(jwt_string)
    if (!isEqual(jwt, tokens)) {
      setJwt(tokens)

      // decodifica token
      const jwt: Token = jwt_decode(tokens.access)
      const rules: Rules = []

      // coloca los permisos
      Object.keys(jwt.rules).forEach((key) => {
        jwt.rules[key].forEach((rule) => {
          rules.push({ action: rule, subject: key })
        })
      })

      // actualiza los permisos del usuario
      dispatch({
        type: 'update',
        rules,
      })
    }

    return tokens
  }

  const logout = () => {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(ls_key)
    setJwt(null)
    dispatch({
      type: 'update',
      rules: [],
    })
  }

  const checkExpiry = (ts: string) => {
    const token: Token = jwt_decode(ts)
    if (token.exp === undefined) {
      return true
    }

    const expirationDate = new Date(token.exp * 1000)

    return moment(expirationDate).isAfter(moment())
  }

  const fetchTokenUpdate = (rt: string) => {
    setIsUpdating(true)
    setIsError(undefined)
    axios
      .get(makeAuthUser(), { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${rt}` } })
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<Tokens>) => {
        storeToken(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error: AxiosError<Tokens>) => {
        setIsError(error)
      })
      .then(() => setIsUpdating(false))
  }

  const getToken = (): getTokenResp => {
    const tokens = retrieveToken()

    if (tokens === null) {
      return { tokens: undefined, updating: isUpdating, error: isError }
    }

    // revisa si el token de acceso esta expirado
    const expired = checkExpiry(tokens.access)
    const expiredRefresh = checkExpiry(tokens.refresh)
    if (expired && expiredRefresh) {
      return { tokens: undefined, updating: isUpdating, error: isError }
    } else if (expired) {
      fetchTokenUpdate(tokens.refresh)
    }

    return { tokens: jwt?.access, updating: isUpdating, error: isError }
  }

  const requestToken = (
    user: string,
    password: string,
    onSuccess?: (t: Tokens) => void
  ) => {
    setIsError(undefined)
    setIsUpdating(true)
    axios
      .post(makeAuthUser(), {
        cuenta: user,
        clave: password,
      })
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<Tokens>) => {
        storeToken(response.data)
        if (onSuccess) onSuccess(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error: AxiosError<Tokens>) => {
        notifyNetworkError(error)
        setIsError(error)
      })
      .then(() => setIsUpdating(false))

    return { tokens: jwt?.access, updating: isUpdating, error: isError }
  }

  return { requestToken, getToken, logout }
}
```

like 133-135 is this fragment of code here:

```
      .catch((error: AxiosError<Tokens>) => {
        notifyNetworkError(error)
        setIsError(error)
      })
      .then(() => setIsUpdating(false))
```

doing a quick search for `u` on my source code I only have one usage of `U` and is for generic declaration:

```
-*- mode: grep; default-directory: "~/code/kue/fero/dev/frontend/" -*-
Grep started at Sat Dec 12 13:18:20

find . -type d \( -path \*/build -o -path \*/SCCS -o -path \*/RCS -o -path \*/CVS -o -path \*/MCVS -o -path \*/.src -o -path \*/.svn -o -path \*/.git -o -path \*/.hg -o -path \*/.bzr -o -path \*/_MTN -o -path \*/_darcs -o -path \*/\{arch\} \) -prune -o \! -type d \( -name \*.map.\*.js -o -name .\#\* -o -name \*.o -o -name \*\~ -o -name \*.bin -o -name \*.lbin -o -name \*.so -o -name \*.a -o -name \*.ln -o -name \*.blg -o -name \*.bbl -o -name \*.elc -o -name \*.lof -o -name \*.glo -o -name \*.idx -o -name \*.lot -o -name \*.fmt -o -name \*.tfm -o -name \*.class -o -name \*.fas -o -name \*.lib -o -name \*.mem -o -name \*.x86f -o -name \*.sparcf -o -name \*.dfsl -o -name \*.pfsl -o -name \*.d64fsl -o -name \*.p64fsl -o -name \*.lx64fsl -o -name \*.lx32fsl -o -name \*.dx64fsl -o -name \*.dx32fsl -o -name \*.fx64fsl -o -name \*.fx32fsl -o -name \*.sx64fsl -o -name \*.sx32fsl -o -name \*.wx64fsl -o -name \*.wx32fsl -o -name \*.fasl -o -name \*.ufsl -o -name \*.fsl -o -name \*.dxl -o -name \*.lo -o -name \*.la -o -name \*.gmo -o -name \*.mo -o -name \*.toc -o -name \*.aux -o -name \*.cp -o -name \*.fn -o -name \*.ky -o -name \*.pg -o -name \*.tp -o -name \*.vr -o -name \*.cps -o -name \*.fns -o -name \*.kys -o -name \*.pgs -o -name \*.tps -o -name \*.vrs -o -name \*.pyc -o -name \*.pyo \) -prune -o \( -path ./node_modules -o -path ./.idea -o -path ./.vscode -o -path ./.ensime_cache -o -path ./.eunit -o -path ./.git -o -path ./.hg -o -path ./.fslckout -o -path ./_FOSSIL_ -o -path ./.bzr -o -path ./_darcs -o -path ./.tox -o -path ./.svn -o -path ./.stack-work -o -path ./.ccls-cache -o -path ./.cache -o -path ./.clangd -o -path ./TAGS -o -path ./\#\*\# -o -path ./\*\~ -o -path ./\*.la -o -path ./\*.o -o -path ./\*.pyc -o -path ./\*.elc -o -path ./\*.exe -o -path ./\*.zip -o -path ./\*.tar.\* -o -path ./\*.rar -o -path ./\*.7z \) -prune -o  -type f \( -name \* -o -name .\* \) -exec grep --color -i -nH --null -e \\bu\\b \{\} +
./.gitlab-ci.yml\027:    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
./src/types/index.ts\05:export type InvoiceCompPropsBase<T, U> = {
./src/types/index.ts\07:  initialValues: U
grep: ./public/icono.png: binary file matches
./yarn.lock\01256:  integrity sha512-entf8ZMOK8sc+8YfeOlM8pCfg3b5+WZIKBfUaaJT8UsjAAPjartzxIYm3TIbjvA4u+u++KbcXD38k682nVHDAQ==
# and more lines like the one above
```

not sure where to start or how to tackle this bug, I know that my login form on development is super slow when you type anything but in production it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the slow down comes from using [react-context-devtools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-devtool)

I'll enable it selectively instead of checking when the code is running for production